# AssertionError on Unit tests after converting a DRF Serializer to a DRF ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I had this previous DRF Serializer that was working fine. But I was asked to change it into a ModelSerializer and now it is not passing all tests.

This is the original version:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from .models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(
        validators=[
            UniqueValidator(
                queryset=User.objects.all(),
                message="A user with that username already exists.",
            )
        ],
    )
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())],
    )
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    full_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    artistic_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)

    def create(self, validated_data: dict) -> User:
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance: User, validated_data: dict) -> User:
        for key, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, key, value)
            if key == 'password':
                instance.set_password(value)

        instance.save()

        return instance
```

And this is MY version:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from .models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields =[
            "id", "username", "email", "full_name", "artistic_name"
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}
```

For some reason, every time I run tests for my version there're three errors which are:

1# AssertionError: False is not true: Check if the password is being updated in PATCH route `/api/users/8/`

2# AssertionError: Items in the first set but not the second:
E 'password': Make sure that all required keys are returned when trying to create a user without data

3# AssertionError: False is not true: check if the password is being properly hashed

I literally tried everything I could possibly think, can anyone help me?

Comment: It would be helpful if you are adding your test cases too in the question.

Comment: You are missing `password` in `fields` which seems to be the root of all your issues.